# "Expression of type "" is not queryable" error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to get an assignment done for class and have hit this error:

> Error 1   Expression of type 'Homework_Code_Examples.Form1.State' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.    D:\Users\Stryke\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Homework Code Examples\Homework Code Examples\Form1.vb    11  32  Homework Code Examples

I've never encountered this before and searching via Google, MSDN and these forums all tell me that I must target the correct .NET framework for my program, however I am completely lost as to which framework I should target as the recommended answers all give the same error upon being recompiled. Currently, I am using .NET Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013.

I don't know if it helps at all or not, but here is my code so that you may see what it is I'm trying to achieve...

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Dim states As State

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        states = New State()

        Dim query = From st In states
                    Let name = states.Name
                    Let density = states.Density()
                    Order By density Descending
                    Select name, density

    End Sub

    Private Sub stateInfo_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles stateInfo.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Class State

        Private m_name, m_abbr, m_date As String
        Private m_area, m_pop As Integer

        Public Property Name()
            Get
                Return m_name
            End Get
            Set(value)
                m_name = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Abbreviation()
            Get
                Return m_abbr
            End Get
            Set(value)
                m_abbr = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property joinDate()
            Get
                Return m_date
            End Get
            Set(value)
                m_date = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property landArea
            Get
                Return m_area
            End Get
            Set(value)
                m_area = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Population
            Get
                Return m_pop
            End Get
            Set(value)
                m_pop = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Function Density()
            Dim popDensity As Integer
            popDensity = Population / landArea
            Return popDensity
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: `states` is a single instance of your `State` class.  It would need to be some sort of collection of states to be queryable.

Comment: @miroxlav, What I'm trying to achieve is to have a list of the states and their population density, ordered by the density, display in a DataGridView box, that part hadn't been coded yet because as soon as I finished my query the error popped up.

Comment: @Mark, you are correct, I neglected to create the array of objects, thanks for that point in the right direction. I'll post back with an update once I've completed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq needs to iterate through multiple objects. In your case, it can be list or collection of **State** class.

#### Example with List(Of Type)

Change line

```vb
   Dim states As State
```

to

```vb
   Dim states As List(Of State)
```

and

```vb
    states = New State()
```

into

```vb
    states = New List(Of State)
```

#### Example with array

Change line

```vb
   Dim states As State
```

to

```vb
   Dim states() As State
```

and

```vb
    states = New State()
```

into

```vb
    ReDim states(10)   'or use a variable inside
```

Comment: I have references to Linq in both lists, any other suggestions? I put up a screenshot here: http://s1280.photobucket.com/user/Stryke_the_Orc/media/linq_zpsxoj1ad1j.jpg.html

Comment: I like your solution, unfortunately, I must use an array of objects, read in from a text file. So I guess now I have an entirely separate problem as the errors now being thrown relate to values of type "String" cannot be converted to an object of the class "State". I'll keep plugging at it until I get it right, thank you for your help!

Comment: Here you have solution using array. :)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, I see the error I was making in your example, I was trying to initialize the array wrong. Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of how to populate your data. I also fix some error in your query. Compare your query to mine to see what I changed.

```
' initialize a list with some values
Dim states = New List(Of State) From {
    New State With {.Name = "Ohio", .Population = 10000, .landArea = 10},
    New State With {.Name = "Texas", .Population = 20000, .landArea = 300},
    New State With {.Name = "Florida", .Population = 5000, .landArea = 1000}
}

' query the list
Dim query = From st In states
        Let name = st.Name
        Let density = st.Density()
        Order By density Descending
        Select name, density
```

I also improve your State class to use proper data type instead of object.

```
Class State

    Private m_name, m_abbr, m_date As String
    Private m_area, m_pop As Integer

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return m_name
        End Get
        Set (value As String)
            m_name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Abbreviation As String
        Get
            Return m_abbr
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_abbr = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property joinDate As String
        Get
            Return m_date
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_date = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property landArea As Integer
        Get
            Return m_area
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_area = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Population As Integer
        Get
            Return m_pop
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_pop = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Density() As Double
        Dim popDensity As Double
        popDensity = Population / landArea
        Return popDensity
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Upvoted because this solution is workable, however the answer i chose was what best fit my specific needs. Thanks!